# Oracle select query with dynamic in clause

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following query

```
    select * from table_1 
    where Conditions in 
         (select case when check_condition = 'Y' then 'Condition_1' 
                 else 'N/A' end as Check_condition 
          from table_2 
          WHERE id = 1122)
```

where table_1 contains the values in column `Conditions` as follows.
Condition_1,Condition_2

This works fine and return me the results.

i want to use multiple select statements inside the `in` clause and I did it as below.

```
    select * from table_1
    where Conditions in (
         select ''''||
             (select case when check_condition = 'Y' then 'Condition_1' 
               else 'N/A' end as Check_condition 
               from table_2 
               WHERE id = 1122)||''''||','''||
                  (select case when check_condition = 'Y' then 'Condition_2'
                        else 'N/A' end as Check_condition 
                  from table_2 WHERE id = 1122)||''''
                 from dual
                )
```

inner query ( inside the in clause) giving me the correct results as expected -

```
'Condition_1','Condition_2'
```

and when I copy paste it to the parent query it works fine and show the results.

```
select * from table_1 where Conditions in ('Condition_1','Condition_2')
```

My issue is, it is not giving any results when I used the second query. I know that sub query will return the results that should match the rows in the outer query. But it shows me empty result set.

I am using oracle 11g

Can anyone please help me out.. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The question is a bit unclear regarding requirements. What I think you want is to select records from `table1` only when:

- rows match 'Condition_1' or 'Condition_2'
- `check_condition` = 'Y'
- there is a row in `table2` with an ID = 1122

It's not clear from your question whether `check_condition` is a column or a variable, and if it is a column to which table it belongs.  Consequently this solution may be wrong but it illustrates the principle.

```
select * from table1 t1
where t1.conditions in ('Condition_1','Condition_2')
and t1.check_condition = 'Y'
and exists
        ( select null from table2 t2
          where t2.id = 1122 )
```

---

If this doesn't provide the solution you need please revise your question  so it states the business logic you need to implement, and also includes relevant tables descriptions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. i got the point. will work on it. appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't ending up with two values passed into the `in` clause like when you do it manually:

```
select * from table_1 where Conditions in ('Condition_1','Condition_2')
```

You're passing a single value which is the concatenation of the values:

```
select * from table_1 where Conditions in ('''Condition_1'',''Condition_2''')
```

And no `condition` matches that concatenated value, so you get no results. You could do something like:

```
select * from table_1 where Conditions in (
  select case when check_condition = 'Y' then 'Condition_1' else 'N/A' end
  from table_2 WHERE id = 1122
  union all
  select case when check_condition = 'Y' then 'Condition_2' else 'N/A' end
  from table_2 WHERE id = 1122
)
```

Or possibly, if I follow what you're doing (which is doubtful as I'm not sure I understand your data model!):

```
select * from table_1 where check_condition != 'Y' or Conditions in (
  select 'Condition_1' from table_2 WHERE id = 1122
  union all
  select 'Condition_2' from table_2 WHERE id = 1122
)
```

It seems like you should be able to do this more cleanly, with joins, but I think we'd need to see the structures and sample data to understand what's going on a bit more.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. i will work on your approach. appreciate your help.

Comment: @sam - I think APC's approach is likely to be closer to what you need (and better, of course, since it only touched `table2` once), but I'll leave this here for the explanation part.